# import flask model from one app to another

Tags: flask

I'm building a project with multiple flask applications and all of them need to share the same database and they both have the same secret key. I have `first_application.py`

```
import os
import enum
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from flask import (
    Flask, jsonify, request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    create_access_token, get_jwt_identity,
    jwt_required, JWTManager
)
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application, support_credentials=True)
db = SQLAlchemy(application)
jwt = JWTManager(application)
application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'same_secret'
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'same_rds_db_uri'


class RoleEnum(enum.Enum):
    waiter = 'waiter'
    manager = 'manager'


class ShiftEnum(enum.Enum):
    night = 'night'
    day = 'day'


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True, nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(
        db.Enum(RoleEnum),
        default=RoleEnum.waiter,
        nullable=False
    )
    shift = db.Column(
        db.Enum(ShiftEnum),
        default=ShiftEnum.night,
        nullable=False
    )
    started_job = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.name


@application.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    password = request.json.get("password", None)
    user = User.query.filter_by(password=password).first_or_404()
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.name)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token)


@application.route("/start-job", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required()
def start_job():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    user = User.query.filter_by(name=current_user)
    user.started_job = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    return jsonify({"message": "Job started"}), 201


with application.app_context():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

and `second_application.py`

```
import os
import enum
from datetime import datetime, timezone

from flask import (
    Flask, jsonify, request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import (
    create_access_token, get_jwt_identity,
    jwt_required, JWTManager
)
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application, support_credentials=True)
db = SQLAlchemy(application)
jwt = JWTManager(application)
application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'same_secret'
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'same_rds_db_uri'


class TableStatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    reserved = 'Reserved'
    free_table = 'Free table'
    preperation = 'Preperation'
    occupied = 'Occupied'


class Table(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    chairs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    status = db.Column(
        db.Enum(TableStatusEnum),
        default=TableStatusEnum.free_table,
        nullable=False
    )
    waiter = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

Now  I need to create one to many relationship between User and Table models. The question is how do I connect them if they are in different environments. I'm using the same AWS RDS database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by connecting you mean *joining*?

*After* creating the tables from two separate applications, you can use [reflection](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/models/#reflecting-tables) to access the other tables that are already in the database.

Comment: so in my case in Table for waiter I should have 
 __table__ = db.metadatas["auth"].tables["user"] right?
If so what is "auth" here?

Comment: Nope, you should follow exactly what documentation says and create another model, which reflects the *already present* User table through `__table__`. Please read more about reflection. Also `auth` is a "bind key" just like the documentation says. You can read more about bind keys [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/binds/#configuring-binds).

Comment: I think I formulated my question poorly. I need to create one to many relationship between User and Table models.

Comment: Are you sure you have to have 2 separate flask apps? Maybe separate your models to an independent module and work with the same module from both apps? What you are trying to achieve is tedious and at this point, I am unable to provide you a good example that achieves what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes sir, I need to have 2 separate flask apps.
I'll make sure to post the solution if I ever find it.

Comment: I ended up having all models in one app so this answer is useful